# when('product').approved trigger multiple times

Tags: in-app-purchase

Iam implementing inapppurchase in ionic 5. iam using cordova plugin for this. here is the link below.

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase

After implementing plugin. Iam facing this issue mention below.

when('product').approved trigger multiple times

is there any solution/suggestion for this ?